# How do I work around that two packages are dependent on the same/similar support library?

Tags: android-support-library, dependency-management, nuget-package, xamarin-studio

I am making an android app in xamarin studio and it needs to have google play services because of google maps api v2 and a QR code scanner for mobile. But when I added zxing.net.mobile to my packages after I had set up google maps and gotten the google play services package, they both fail as they are both dependent on the 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' package.

I have tried this on two different solutions and the same thing happens.

I have looked into this on google and stack overflow and found dependency hell on wikipedia, but I can not seem to apply that to NuGet packages when using Xamarin Studio. [Dependency hell on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell)

And i found this reason for it: [Question answer without full explanation on how to do this.](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/46845/#Comment_46845)

So how does this work, where do I look to change to only using Xamarin.Android.Support.V4 for both ZXing.net and google play services?

Error:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error: Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll'
   at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() (TrailMapplication)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what I had to do, and it solved that problem: I went to my project on my computer and looked into

C:\Users\Name\Documents\Projects\Solution\Project\bin\Debug

and deleted a Mono.Android.Services.v4.dll and added the Xamarin.Android.Services.v4.dll instead.

Had to Re-build the project though but then it worked.